# Set height for color input

Tags: html, css

How do I set the height for a color input? I can set the width, but height doesn't work at all.

```css
input {
  border        : #0f0 2px solid;
  border-radius : 5px;
  font-size     : 12px;
  height        : 20px !important;
  width         : 30%;
  background    : #0000;
}
```

```html
<input type="color" id="color">
<input type="text" value="this one works but not the other">
```

Comment: You miss a space before `!important`.

Comment: You don't need `!importaant`. The height will work just fine, it is 20px. Try increasing the height, it will work just fine.

Comment: It does seem to be that you think it's not increasing because the text next to it happens to be the same size. Copy the snippet, use `height: 200px` and you'll see it's doing exactly what is expected.

Comment: Why not call on your ID? I think it may be an oversight on your code height that is the same as the default height of a color input bar.

Comment: @RinkeshGolwala No, it doesn't work fine on Firefox

Answer (score 1):

use `box-sizing : border-box;` first

```css
input {
  box-sizing     : border-box;
  vertical-align : top;
  border         : #0f0 2px solid;
  border-radius  : 5px;
  font-size      : 12px;
  height         : 20px;
  background     : #0000;
  width          : 20em;
  }
```

```html
  <input type="color" id="color" >
   
  <input type="text" value="this one works but not the other">
```